# Delete Flash Cookies via Code

Tags: c#, browser, watin, browser-automation

Using C# (or VB if needed), I am setting up a simple automated browser program.  Right now I am doing this via watin.  I am doing this on my Windows 7 Desktop and the browser I am automating via Watin is IE.  Ideally I would like to keep it as is, in C# using watin, but I am flexible.

Each time I run the program I would like to delete the cookies, which with watin is simple to execute.  The problem I have is deleting the flash cookies.

I know to manually delete the cookies you can do it here, but I'd like to figure out a way to do it via programming [FLASH COOKIES SETTINGS](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html#117717)

Also, here is a [Great paper on Flash Cookies and Privacy](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1446862)

Please let me know if I left anything out, or what I can do to make this question as clear as possible.

Comment: @ is the swf you're using something you've written or some third party's?

Comment: I'm concerned about the sites I'm browsing using the browser's flash cookies to track me.  So if I visit a site with flash content I don't want those cookies to be used to identify me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post for a simple batch file that does this: http://www.ardamis.com/2010/07/07/how-to-delete-flash-cookies/ .  This can easily be converted to C# or (you can shell out to the batch file) and executed from your test suite init.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as your answer (if this is what you were looking for) :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [SOLReader](http://www.sephiroth.it/python/solreader.php) to delete the relevant [LSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object) data.